# ionic 1 crash on first run after installing from google play

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, ionic-v1

I am using ionic 1, app is crashed at first time only after installing from google play. After it works fine.

The error on google play

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaqc.zzbm (Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver.onReceive (Unknown Source)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:2758)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900 (ActivityThread.java:153)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1452)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5527)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:739)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:629)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:511)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:469)
```

Plugin list

cordova-plugin-apprate 1.3.0 "AppRate"

cordova-plugin-camera 4.0.3   "Camera"

cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"

cordova-plugin-console 1.0.5 "Console"

cordova-plugin-datepicker 0.9.2 "DatePicker"

cordova-plugin-device 1.1.4 "Device"

cordova-plugin-dialogs 2.0.1    "Notification"

cordova-plugin-facebook4 2.0.1 "Facebook Connect"

cordova-plugin-file 6.0.1 "File"

cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.7.1  "File Transfer"

cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.4.1 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-globalization 1.11.0 "Globalization"
cordova-plugin-google-analytics 1.8.3 "Google Universal Analytics Plugin"

cordova-plugin-googleplus 5.1.1 "Google SignIn"
cordova-plugin-image-picker 1.1.1 "ImagePicker"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 3.0.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-nativestorage 2.2.2 "NativeStorage"
cordova-plugin-network-information 2.0.1 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.1 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.1 "StatusBar"

cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1 "Whitelist"

cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.1.6 "SocialSharing"

cordova-plugin-x-toast 2.6.0 "Toast"
cordova-sqlite-storage 1.5.3 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"

Which plugin caused the crash? or its other problems?

Comment: Have you resolve this issue? I am getting same issue.

Answer (score 0):

May these issues can be happen due plugin problems.Try to rebuild the project by removing these plugins and install new version of same plugins.